# Meaning of each in following sentence

Tags: comprehension

Which statement is true about this sentence?

> **Each** time X did the puzzle right, Y gave him a reward.

1. X **always** did the puzzle right
2. X **sometimes** did the puzzle wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. There's no way to tell how many failures there were as written. The original phrasing could mean that Y gave a reward for every one of 15 successes and no failures, or that Y gave a reward for the only two successes out of 20 tries.

It *is* implied that X did the puzzle right at least once or twice, though, because otherwise it would have been better to use irrealis mood (which implies that something didn't actually happen), like this:

> Each time X did the puzzle right, Y **would have** given him a reward.

Or this, which uses a statement of intent ("going to") along with the past tense to imply that the intent wasn't followed by an actual event:

> Each time X did the puzzle right, Y **was going to** give him a reward.

---

In order for statement #1 to be true, the sentence would have to be something like this:

> X did the puzzle several times, and Y gave him a reward for doing it right each time.

Here, "each" connects the reward (and, using "for", the success as well) back to every one of the *attempts*, not the successes.

For statement #2 to be true, the sentence might look like this:

> X did the puzzle several times, and each time X **managed to** do the puzzle right, Y gave him a reward.

The sentence starts with the same emphasis on multiple attempts, but uses "manage to" to imply that there was a decent chance of *not* doing it. Together, those two elements suggest that X's successes were rare enough to be worth noting.